# Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service Application not Created successfully

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, central-administration, farm-admin, sharepoint-administration

We need to create "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service Application" in SharePoint 2016.

using below power-shell command to create Subscription Services, after long time its showing request timeout.

```
New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication –ApplicationPool SSASPool –Name SSAS2016 –DatabaseName DBName –DatabaseServer DBServerName
```

In Central Admin status of Subscription is Starting and cannot be change.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the official document:

*SharePoint won't complete the service application creation till the correspondent service instance is started on all the concerned servers in the farm. While waiting, if this is taking long time to start the service instance, the service application creation may timeout and cause this issue.*

Try to start the service instance with PowerShell
(Remember to change the server name):

```
Get-SPServiceInstance | ?{$_.TypeName -eq "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service" -and $_.Server.Name -eq "ServerName"} | Start-SPServiceInstance
```

Then check the status using:

```
Get-SPServiceInstance | ?{$_.TypeName -eq "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service" -and $_.Server.Name -eq "ServerName"}
```

After that, run the command again:

```
$sa = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication -ApplicationPool 'SharePoint Web Services Default' -Name 'Subscriptions Settings Service Application' -DatabaseName 'Subscription'
New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy -ServiceApplication $sa
```

Make sure you run the PowerShell command with Administrator account.

Here’s your references:

[SharePoint Service Application is Stuck on Starting.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ahmedamin/sharepoint-service-application-stuck-on-starting)

[New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/new-spsubscriptionsettingsserviceapplication?view=sharepoint-ps)

[SharePoint 2016: Subscription Settings Service Application Step by Step.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33967.sharepoint-2016-subscription-settings-service-application-step-by-step.aspx)